# Atom editor r-language error - Failed to load snippets

Tags: r, atom-editor

Every time I open my Atom editor on my Windows 10 PC I get the following errors. How do I eliminate these errors?

```
Failed to load snippets from 'C:\Users\stackinator.atom\packages\language-r\snippets\language-r.cson'

C:\Users\stackinator\.atom\packages\language-r\snippets\language-r.cson: Duplicate key 'Cummulative max'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is caused by a [bug](https://github.com/lee-dohm/language-r/blob/master/snippets/language-r.cson#L14-L19) in the snippets provided by the `language-r` package. Since the package has been deprecated by its author, there won't be updates fixing this.

The easiest option is to install [`atom-language-r`](https://github.com/REditorSupport/atom-language-r/tree/master/snippets) instead.

Alternatively, you can edit the snippet to fix that typo. It should look like this:

```
'Cummulative min':
  'prefix': 'cumi'
  'body': 'cummin(${1:x})'
'Cummulative max':
  'prefix': 'cuma'
  'body': 'cummax(${1:x})'
```

**Note:** I have changed the first *"Cumulative max"* to *"Cumulative min"*.

Comment: performed your edit and get this error `C:\Users\stackinator\.atom\packages\language-r\snippets\language-r.cson: Duplicate key 'Grep'` Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: It's basically the same as before. There are two identically named keys "Grep" in the snippets, so you need to rename one of them.

Comment: Just to confirm, the `'Cumulative min':` has `'body': 'cummax'` not `'cummin'` and visa versa for `'Cumulative max'`?

Comment: probably off-topic but the sea of deprecated atom packages makes things very confusing

Answer (score 3):

Apart from changing  "Cumulative max" to "Cumulative min", you also might need to remove the first 'Grep' along with its prefix and body since there are 2 'Grep' present